# html2canvas overlapping words when it pass html to canvas object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html2canvas

I'm trying to use html2canvas.js to generate an image by html content  but when I'm calling the script it is overlapping the words you can see it here [print of issue](http://hdb.sosbarreiro.com/issues.jpg) or if you want can  see it working [here](http://hdb.sosbarreiro.com/cupon/E572B3D442D544/) I already tried to find some solution at  good but I'm getting nothing till now, the script is following bellow.

```
function cupon_gera(){
        $(".ancup").hide();
        $(".encup").show();
        html2canvas($("#cpg"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            $("#txt").val(dataURL);
            },
            width:430
        });
    }
```

pls help-me cause i can't see the way to fix it. thanks.

Comment: it works perfect for me in chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: @user2352577L I am using  Google Chrome too the latest version

Comment: i am using google chrome version 50 http://tinypic.com/r/fk4oqp/9

Comment: Or you have cache the javascript file